# Acumatica - DataView LSAMProdItem_lotseropts

Tags: acumatica

In the Production order maintenance screen the inspect element shows the DataView -  LSAMProdItem_lotseropts on the APSX page used as DATAMEMBER for the tab

But on Graph this data view is not defined,

How can I get to this Dataview???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special view, generated in code, inside the specialized view declaration

```
public LSAMProdItem lsSelectItem;
```

The logic is in LSSelect which is the base for LSAMProdItem class, and looks like this (where in your case, in production order, *this* is the LSAMProdItem object):

```
graph.Views.Add(this.Prefixed("lotseropts")...
```